# $X=Spec(A)$. $X=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^N D(f_i)\Rightarrow (f_1, ..., f_N)=A$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $X=Spec(A)$ and note $D(f)\simeq Spec(A_f)$. $X=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^N D(f_i)\Rightarrow (f_1, ..., f_N)=A$

We used this to proof a special case of $\mathscr{O}$ the sheaf of rings is a sheaf.
I tried to show the implication but I get stuck:
$X=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^N D(f_i)=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^N X\backslash V(f_i) = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^N \{\mathfrak{p}|f_i\not\subset\mathfrak{p}\}$. But I don't know how to do the step to get $A = (f_1, ..., f_N)$.

Comment: Please do not mix words and logical symbols. To me the statement reads as "if this implication holds" (and then no conclusion). I had to read it again to figure out that what you meant.

Comment: Uh, sorry. And thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if $X = \bigcup_i D(f_i)$ then this is equivalent to saying that $\bigcap_i V(f_i) = \emptyset$.

On the left-hand side, we have that

$$
\bigcap_i V(f_i) = \bigcap_i Spec\big(A/(f_i)\big) = Spec\big(A/(f_1, \ldots, f_n)\big)
$$

On the right-hand side, however, we have $\emptyset$ which is Spec of the zero ring. What can you conclude from this?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have one more question... I see how the second equation solves the problem, but I don't see the first. Why holds $\bigcap\limits_i V(f_i)=\bigcap\limits_i(a/(f_i))$. Could you please explain me this step?

Comment: I meant $\bigcap\limits_i V(f_i)=\bigcap\limits Spec(A/(f_i))$ :)

Comment: For a given ideal $I \subset A$, there is a bijection between the ideals $J$ such that $I \subset J \subset A$ and the ideals of $A/I$.

If you apply this to the ideal $I = (f_i)$...